# Recover Ubuntu after change of SysRq

Tags: boot, 20.04, sysrq

On my Ubuntu 20.04, I wanted to change the SysRq value permanently with the command

```
# echo "kernel.sysrq = 244" >> /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
```

Since I did this, whenever I boot the device with Ubuntu, it loads way slower and
I cannot get past the login window: I type in the password, it loads for a while, then
reloads the login window again.

I would appreciate any hint on how to solve this.

The first part of the output to

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

is

```
9.651s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
4.782s plymouth-quit-wait.service
2.862s snapd.service
2.568s gpu-manager.service
2.034s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d4df8b86\x2d8308\x2da564\x2da0aeaf39e6a4.swap
1.175s dev-nvme0n1p5.device
640ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount
```

After restarting the device again, now beside the above the following appeared as well:

```
2.437s dev-loop3.device
2.411s dev-loop5.device
2.265s dev-loop9.device
2.222s dev-loop8.device
2.188s dev-loop7.device
2.185s dev-loop6.device
2.077s dev-loop10.device
```

Comment: Are you sure it's actually related?

Comment: No. I only know that before the change, it booted without any problems but now it doesn't. Can you think of anything else, why this happens?

Comment: [Edit] your question with the output of `systemd-analyze blame` - this command tells you what took time during boot.